# FB.FeedShare in Unity does not render text or image

Tags: c#, facebook, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to implement FeedShare into Unity. I want a player to be able to post a message on his/ her FaceBook. I followed the docs on FaceBook's own site with the link to the newest SDK version, which I am using.

I can succesfully use the example link provided by them (https://example.com/myapp/?storyID=thelarch), but when i try to implement my own site and text, I do not get the correct text.

Code:

```
public void PostToFaceBook()
{
    FB.FeedShare(
    link: new Uri("https://mysite/mypage.html"),
    linkName: "MyTitle",
    linkDescription: "My Description.",
    picture: new Uri("https://mysite/mylogo.png")
    );
}
```

HTML site:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
    <title>LetterSwipe</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxxxxx" /> 
<meta property="og:title" content="LetterSwipe!" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Ik heb zojuist gewonnen met letter swipe!" />
<meta property="og:type" content="game" /> 
<meta property="og:image" content="https://letterswipe.com/logo_LetterSwipe.png" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.letterswipe.android" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="LetterSwipe"/>

    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: #f0f0f2;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

    }
    div {
        width: 600px;
        margin: 5em auto;
        padding: 50px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 1em;
    }
    a:link, a:visited {
        color: #38488f;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    @media (max-width: 700px) {
        body {
            background-color: #fff;
        }
        div {
            width: auto;
            margin: 0 auto;
            border-radius: 0;
            padding: 1em;
        }
    }
    </style>    
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <h1>LetterSwipe</h1>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p><a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.letterswipe.android">View in playstore</a></p>
</div>


</body></html>
```

The facebook settings in Unity seem to be correct, because I can login with FaceBook and I can post to my wall. However the post popup is like this:

[image]

And the annoying part is that if i switch the URL back to the one provided in the example, i get the desired result (however with an example text).

What am i missing here? I find the FaceBook documentation very lacking on this part.

*Note, I can succesfully post on FaceBook and the text provided on my screenshot will show up on my wall (with a working appstore link). That is not the issue.

Comment: You have to add open graph tags on your website. Those will be used to create the preview.

Comment: I tried to do so and followed the docs, placing the various tags (updated my question). However, the result remains exactly the same. Any idea?

Comment: Your og:url should point to the url you are sharing. You point it to https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.letterswipe.android

Comment: I managed to figure that out, yes thanks. However my problem was that i had to manually scrape the page on the facebook developer site and change my png image to a jpg image. The png wouldnt load for some reason.